# File data type causes error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant:File

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to create a simple text file via Flash, and I'm following the code given by Adobe in its help documents:

```
var file:File = file.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("test.txt");
var str:String = "Hello";
file.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, fileSaved); 
file.save(str); 
function fileSaved(event:Event):void 
 { 
   trace("Done."); 
 }
```

The problem being Flash spits out the error 1406: type not found. I tried to search about this error, and it's usually about movie linkage or tweening. My problem rises from the fact that I use this code:

```
var file:File
```

The presence of that code alone causes the error. The SWF exports just fine without it. The type "File" also doesn't appear in IntelliSense. I'm stumped. I think I don't have the proper package, but how come I don't have the proper package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `File` class is in the `flash.filesystem.File` namespace so make sure you are importing that if you want to use it. What is probably tripping you up though is the `File` class is only available when targeting the AIR runtime *not* the normal flash player runtime. Make sure you are trying this in an AIR project.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks. I didn't notice the help's title. It was a help data for Adobe AIR environment. I've tried using Adobe AIR project and it works now.